# Vs2013 Nodejs project.. 2nd box..."specified executable is not a valid applications for this OS platfrom

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio-2013, tfs, ntvs

I have a nodejs project in Vs2013

I built it on a w7, 64 bit machine, and it's working, on my main box, check it into TFS and it builds and runs test in Team city. Also runs from a batch file that calls protractor.cmd directly.

I pulled it down on a second box, windows 7, 64 bit

installed Java jdk, VS Node tools, node.js, protractor, VS2013 update 4.

If I run it from the batch file it runs fine. If  a debug the project in vs2013 it crashes with the error above

The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

There are some SO questions that says node.exe is the problem but I searched my drive (with agent ransack) and can't find node.exe anywhere.

I uninstalled the 64 JDK and installed the 32 bit JDK and no joy..

I'm assuming I've installed the wrong version of something.. but I don't know what

Any Ideas? Any Help Is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you added Node.exe to the path.

---

You said you installed nodejs, so look for Node.exe in something like C:\Program Files\nodejs\

If you can't find Node.exe, then uninstall nodejs and reinstall it and pay attention to where it installs.

---

Now that you have Node.exe, add it to the path by

- right click on My Computer
- select Properties
- activate the Advanced tab
- click the Environment Variables button
- edit the Path system variable

Comment: Also when we installed node on the D: drive it didnt' work, we uninstalled and reinstalled on the C: drive it worked on my coworkers boss.. Also do be sure to reboot if you have similar issues, some environment variables don't seem to get set till reboot.